# How can i retrieve the values matching to an id in solidity

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract tracking  {

  struct  data  {
    uint   ownernumber;
    uint   id;
  }

  uint value;
  mapping (uint256 => data) public  datamatching;

  function storedata (uint _ownernumber, uint _id) public {

    var  persondata  = datamatching[value];
    persondata .ownernumber = _ownernumber;
    persondata. id  =  _id;

  }

  function getData(uint256 userId) returns (uint){

   }
}
```

1) I wrote a function to store the values in my solidity code

2) Now in getData function, I want the user to enter the `ownernumber` and get all the details  matching to the `ownernumber` is it possible please help me

> **Common errors:**
>
> Use of the "var" keyword is disallowed.  Data location must be
>
> "storage" or "memory" for variable, but none was given

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do this.

1. You can return multiple variables from a function, like this:

   ```
   pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

   contract tracking  {

     struct  data  {
       uint   ownernumber;
       uint   id;
     }

     uint value;
     mapping (uint256 => data) public  datamatching;

     function storedata (uint _ownernumber, uint _id) public {
       var  persondata  = datamatching[value];
       persondata .ownernumber = _ownernumber;
       persondata. id  =  _id;
     }

     function getData(uint256 userId) returns (uint, uint){
       return (datamatching[userId].ownernumber, datamatching[userId].id);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Alternatively you can use the experimental v2 abi encoder that allows returning structs from functions, like this:

   ```
   pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
   pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

   contract tracking  {

     struct  data  {
       uint   ownernumber;
       uint   id;
     }

     uint value;
     mapping (uint256 => data) public  datamatching;

     function storedata (uint _ownernumber, uint _id) public {
       var  persondata  = datamatching[value];
       persondata .ownernumber = _ownernumber;
       persondata. id  =  _id;
     }

     function getData(uint256 userId) returns (data){
       return datamatching[userId];
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to retrieve `data` by `ownernumber` as there is no way to iterate mappings unless you know the keys.

You can store all the all the keys of the mappings in an array so that you can iterate mappings and retrieve data for specific `ownernumber`. The time complexity of this approach will be **O(N)**.

I am assuming there is one to many relationship among owner and data. That is one `owner` is associated with many `data`. If it is so then you can reduce the time complexity of retrieving data by owner to **O(1)**. Refer the folowing blog for more details -

https://medium.com/@robhitchens/enforcing-referential-integrity-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-a9ab1427ff42

I think you need to pass `value` as an argument to `storedata` function. Let me know if any further details are required.

Hopr it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**A sample program:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

contract bank{
struct Person{
    uint id;
    bytes32 name;
}
mapping(address => Person) public  p;

function getDetails(address a) public view returns(uint ,bytes32){
     Person storage person = p[a];
    return(person.id , person.name);
}
function setDetails(address a,uint id , bytes32 name) public{
    Person storage person = p[a];
    person.id = id;
    person.name = name;
}
}
```

**Note**: Now, if you use var keyword like `var person = p[a];` , you will get below **SyntaxError**:

> **SyntaxError**: Use of the "var" keyword is disallowed. Use explicit
>   declaration `struct bank.Person storage pointer person = ...´ instead.

If you use Person person = p[a]; , then you will get **TypeError** :

> **TypeError**: Data location must be "storage" or "memory" for
>   variable, but none was given.
>            Person person = p[a];

So better Option is to use `storage` keyword along with *Struct* name like below:

```
Person storage person = p[a];
```